# Python Socket Handling Multiple Connection

Tags: python

I'd like to let more than one client connect to my server, and have the server send them different items. For example send "hi" to the first client and "goodbye" to the second . Here's my code:

```
Server

import socket
file_num = 0
inp = raw_input("Name of the wordlist file = ")
inp2 = input("Number of lines for every wordlist = ")
with open(inp) as in_file:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(in_file):
        print line_num
        if not line_num % inp2:
            file_num += 1
        with open("out{0}.txt".format(file_num), "a") as out_file:
            out_file.writelines(line)
def upload(host, port):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    filename = open("out1.txt", "rb")
    print "Server Waiting for client on port ", port
    while 1:
        client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
        print "Connection from ", address
        while 1:
            for line in filename:
                server_data = line
                if server_data.lower() == 'q':
                    client_socket.send(server_data)
                    client_socket.close()
                    break
                else:
                    client_socket.send(server_data)

                client_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
                if client_data.lower() == 'q':
                    print "Quit from client"
                    client_socket.close()
                    break
                else:
                    print "<-- client: ", client_data
        break
upload("localhost", 4000)
```

and then my client program

```
Client

import socket

port = 4000
host_server = "localhost"
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((host_server, port))
z = 1
print "Type 'Q' or 'q' to QUIT"
f = open("pino.txt", "w")
while 1:
    server_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    f.writelines(server_data)
    if server_data.lower() == 'q':
        print "Quit from server"
        client_socket.close()
        break
    else:
        print "<-- server: ", server_data
        client_data = ("Sent "+str(z))
        z = z+1
        if client_data.lower() != 'q':
            client_socket.send(client_data)
        else:
            client_socket.send(client_data)
            client_socket.close()
            break
f.close()
```

Hope you give me the solution cause this will be cool if it works, another thing I'd like for this program is if the filename under `def upload` would change for every client. For example the first client will get out1 and the 7th will get out7. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm new to python so if you could explain me what you changed it would be great, don't ask me to use Twisted cause Id like to do this with the normal python socket .

Comment: Look at the select module.

Comment: The [`select`](http://devdocs.io/python/library/select) library is for this purpose. Or you can use third party libraries like Twisted.

Comment: Uhmm can you please write me an example of using the select library? I don't like using third parts libraries so i'll be glad if you give me and example. I am working on windows 7 and i saw that there are some problem with my operative system and select , is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem myself :-)

So what you're trying to do is have multiple connections, however usually socket uses the main thread, making it hard to have more than one connection.

To fix this we need to use something called *Threading*, it allows you to surpass operations onto other threads. So you need to create a new thread when every connection is made:

```
import socket
from _thread import *

file_num = 0
inp = raw_input("Name of the wordlist file = ")
inp2 = input("Number of lines for every wordlist = ")
with open(inp) as in_file:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(in_file):
        print line_num
        if not line_num % inp2:
            file_num += 1
        with open("out{0}.txt".format(file_num), "a") as out_file:
            out_file.writelines(line)
def upload(host, port):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    filename = open("out1.txt", "rb")
    print "Server Waiting for client on port ", port
    while 1:
        client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
        print "Connection from ", address
        while 1:
            for line in filename:
                server_data = line
                if server_data.lower() == 'q':
                    client_socket.send(server_data)
                    client_socket.close()
                    break
                else:
                    client_socket.send(server_data)

                client_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
                if client_data.lower() == 'q':
                    print "Quit from client"
                    client_socket.close()
                    break
                else:
                    print "<-- client: ", client_data
        break
start_new_thread(upload, ("localhost", 4000))
#NOTICE!!! If this line doesn't work ^^^
#Then replace it with:
#thread.start_new_thread(upload, ("localhost", 4000))
```

Hope this helps! :-)

Please tell me if it doesn't,
for I have *not* tested this, I've just done it before :)

Thanks,

*~Coolq*